# Free pointer to an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

In my program I have a structure that looks like this:

```
struct structure {
    int n;
    int *arr;
};
```

And I allocate memory for arr like this:

```
structure->arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * arr_size);
```

Now here is where I start to get confused, and I am not sure if I am doing it right. What I want to do is use "arr" as an array to store or access integers. So I set arr to point to an array that I created and filled with 0's:

```
int new_arr[i];
structure.arr = new_arr;
```

I am not sure if this is right, but so far I don't get any errors. So I create another array that stores these structures, and I insert some new structures in it. But when I try to free the member arr from any of the structures inside the array (like this `free(&array_of_struct[i].arr);`) I get an error:

```
==747==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: 0x7fffd7c6ad08 in thread T0

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: bad-free (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10d7cf) in __interceptor_free
==747==ABORTING
```

So I think I understand what the problem is, but I have no idea how to solve it. I don't imagine this is the way I'm supposed to point to an array, so can anyone tell me how to do it right?

**UPDATE**

So instead of writing "structure.arr = new_arr" I am now using memset this way:

```
memset(structure.arr, '\0', array_size * sizeof(int));
```

But I still get the same arror when trying to free structure.arr. Also if I try to use mempcy. Could there be something wrong with `free(&array_of_struct[i].arr)`?

**UPDATE2**

So I actually managed to use mempcy and free member "arr". The problem is, that I can only do it before I append the structure to my array of structures. If I try to free it after that (as a member of the array) I get the errors.

**LAST UPDATE**

I have managed to make it work with memset. The problem was that I had to write `free(array_of_struct[i].arr)` instead of `free(&array_of_struct[i].arr)`
Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Why are you trying to free the array?

Comment: So do you want `arr` to point to your dynamically allocated array or to some array with automatic/static storage duration? Those two things work differently, you obviously cannot `free` something that wasn't `malloc`'d

Comment: @klutt I am trying to free the member "arr" from the structur, because otherwise I get memory leaks.

Comment: If you don't malloc, then don't free.

Comment: @UnholySheep I want my structure to have two flexible arrays, since I  cant know the their size until I create them. So I use pointers for that.

Comment: @klutt But I do use malloc. I allocate memory for the array in member "arr". Can you initialize the structure otherwise?

Comment: I think you need to read a bit deeper about pointers and dynamic allocation. But you should use memcpy or something like that here.

Comment: Quick answer: you can use `free` with pointers that have previously been returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
structure.arr = new_arr;
```

That's not a copy of array content.  That simply reassigns the pointer.

That means you are replacing the pointer with an allocation from somewhere else. At best, you'll have a memory leak from not freeing the original allocation. At worst, you'll crash because you attempt to free `new_arr` which is a stack array (invalid to invoke free on that address).

Do this instead, copy the array contents instead of overwriting the pointer:

```
memcpy(structure.arr, new_arr, arr_size * sizeof(int));
```

But if you just want to "zero out" the original allocation (as you implied), you just need to do this:

```
memset(structure.arr, '\0', arr_size * sizeof(int));
```

Or just use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to allocate and zero-out the contents at the same time.

```
structure->arr = calloc(arr_size, sizeof(int));
```

**Update**

> But I still get the same arror when trying to free structure.arr. Also if I try to use mempcy. Could there be something wrong with free(&array_of_struct[i].arr)?

You need to pass to `free` exactly what was assigned from malloc.

So instead of this:

```
free(&array_of_struct[i].arr);
```

This:

```
free(array_of_struct[i].arr);
```

Comment: If I try to zero out i get this warning: "warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 2)"

Comment: You'd have to show the code where that warning is getting generated for me to diagnose.

Comment: You still have to invoke `malloc` before invoking memset.

Comment: Ok, I actually managed to use memset. But I still cant free it. And how do I access the elements of "arr" if I do this?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you you to invoke `free` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error since you can free only memory that was malloc'd.
when you write `int new_arr[SIZE]` you allocate the array on the stack, so you don't need to free it (you can say it will be "freed" when you leave the function in which you allocated it).

As for your struct, if you're aiming for an array that has a constant size that you know in advance, I would recommend that you implement it like this:

```
struct my_struct {
    int arr[SIZE];
}
```

This will allocate the array as part of the struct (in my opinion this is more readable). So when you define an instance of this struct in your program it's sufficient to write:

```
struct my_struct s;
```

and the array will be allocated as well. In this case, you won't need to free it since you won't malloc it.

If you don't know the size of the array in advance, then it would be better to first allocate the memory using malloc and then use memcpy like @selbie suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p = malloc(size);
int arr[size];
p = arr; // Not good. The memory we allocated above is now lost.
free(?); // We don't have a pointer to the allocated memory
```

```
int *p = malloc(size);
int arr[size];
int *q = arr;
p = arr; // Ok, because we have saved the pointer so we can free later
free(q);
```

```
int *p = malloc(size);
int arr[size];
memcpy(p, arr, size * sizeof *p);
free(p); // Works fine. We have not overwritten the pointer
```